# What functionality does this file type perform?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Previously worked with `Nuxt.js2` but now I need to work with `VUE3 Typescript` bundle.
There is such a project:
[image]
Question:
What functionality does this file type, highlighted with yellow icons, perform?
What is its purpose?

Comment: Could you update your question with a screenshot  of what the contents of a `.vue.js` looks like?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/GrqlZnXCzvXzkA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing a couple of options in the linter settings for the typescript.

[image: http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHdb4b7m]